# How to avoid having webpack to load unnecessary package files?

Tags: webpack

[`cldr-data`](https://github.com/rxaviers/cldr-data-npm) is an npm module that holds Unicode CLDR data, which is huge (~250 MB, lots of JSON files). Developers can cherry-pick the JSON files directly, e.g., `require("cldr-data/supplemental/likelySubtags")` or they can use its API, e.g., `require("cldr-data")("supplemental/likelySubtags")` (which will `return require("./" + path)` relatively to the module obviously).

When cherry-picking the JSON files directly, webpack resolves the straightforward requirements and it works just fine.

```
// "cldr-data/supplemental/likelySubtags.json" is a JSON file.
var likelySubtags = require("cldr-data/supplemental/likelySubtags");
```

quick build:

```
$ npm run build

> globalize-hello-world-webpack@ build /tmp/globalize-hello-world-webpack
> webpack

Hash: 4cb435ab9977c41bb6e0
Version: webpack 1.9.12
Time: 420ms
    Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  323 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./main.js 1.26 kB {0} [built]
    + 18 hidden modules
```

When using the API, webpack gets crazy with "request of a dependency is an expression".

```
// "cldr-data/supplemental/likelySubtags.json" is a JSON file.
var cldrData = require("cldr-data");
var likelySubtags = cldrData("supplemental/likelySubtags");
```

looooooong intensive-CPU broken build:

```
npm run build
Hash: 74a65b11c84ec356ac8d
Version: webpack 1.9.12
Time: 496679ms
    Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  173 MB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./main.js 1.54 kB {0} [built]
   [1] . ^\.\/.*$ 363 bytes {0} [built] [3 warnings]
   [2] ./README.md 0 bytes [optional] [built] [failed]
   [4] ./output/bundle.js 323 kB {0} [optional] [built]
   [6] ./webpack.config.js 359 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
    + 12155 hidden modules

WARNING in ./main.js
Critical dependencies:
10:1-39 the request of a dependency is an expression
7:1-44 the request of a dependency is an expression
8:1-42 the request of a dependency is an expression
9:1-42 the request of a dependency is an expression
11:1-49 the request of a dependency is an expression
12:1-50 the request of a dependency is an expression
13:1-44 the request of a dependency is an expression
14:1-45 the request of a dependency is an expression
15:1-45 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./main.js 10:1-39 7:1-44 8:1-42 9:1-42 11:1-49 12:1-50 13:1-44 14:1-45 15:1-45

WARNING in ./~/cldr-data/DCO.md
Module parse failed: /tmp/globalize-hello-world-webpack/node_modules/cldr-data/DCO.md Line 1: Unexpected identifier
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| If you would like to make a contribution to cldr-data-npm, please certify to the following:
| 
| ---
 @ ./~/cldr-data ^\.\/.*$

WARNING in ./~/cldr-data/LICENSE
Module parse failed: /tmp/globalize-hello-world-webpack/node_modules/cldr-data/LICENSE Line 1: Unexpected identifier
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| UNICODE, INC. LICENSE AGREEMENT - DATA FILES AND SOFTWARE
| 
|     Unicode Data Files include all data files under the directories
 @ ./~/cldr-data ^\.\/.*$

WARNING in ./~/cldr-data/LICENSE-MIT
Module parse failed: /tmp/globalize-hello-world-webpack/node_modules/cldr-data/LICENSE-MIT Line 1: Unexpected number
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| Copyright (c) 2013 Rafael Xavier de Souza http://rafael.xavier.blog.br
| 
| Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person
 @ ./~/cldr-data ^\.\/.*$

WARNING in ./~/cldr-data/README.md
Module parse failed: /tmp/globalize-hello-world-webpack/node_modules/cldr-data/README.md Line 1: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| # cldr-units-modern
| 
| This repository provides the a portion of the JSON distribution of CLDR locale data
 @ ./~/cldr-data ^\.\/.*$

WARNING in ./~/cldr-data/install.js
Module parse failed: /tmp/globalize-hello-world-webpack/node_modules/cldr-data/install.js Line 50: Illegal return statement
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     "listed under `dependencies` of the `package.json` of your application."
|   );
|   return process.exit(0);
| }
| 
 @ ./~/cldr-data ^\.\/.*$

WARNING in . ^\.\/.*$
Module not found: Error: a dependency to an entry point is not allowed
 @ . ^\.\/.*$

WARNING in . ^\.\/.*$
Module not found: Error: a dependency to an entry point is not allowed
 @ . ^\.\/.*$

WARNING in ./README.md
Module parse failed: /tmp/globalize-hello-world-webpack/README.md Line 1: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| # Hello World (Webpack)
| 
| Project loading `globalize` through `webpack`:
 @ . ^\.\/.*$

ERROR in ./~/cldr-data/Gruntfile.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'matchdep' in /tmp/globalize-hello-world-webpack/node_modules/cldr-data
 @ ./~/cldr-data/Gruntfile.js 40:2-23
```

[`cldr-data` exported API](https://github.com/rxaviers/cldr-data-npm/blob/c8c08f4b8735f9daf05c27edfaf34bf2b22739f5/index.js#L49-L60) uses dynamic requierments and it's making webpack crazy. I suppose [require contexts](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#automatically-created-contexts-defaults-module-xxxcontextxxx) could help me out in this scenario given [#196](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/196). But, I have no idea how.

Find the question files here: https://github.com/unindented/globalize-hello-world-webpack/.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is use static strings like `require("cldr-data/<path>")`.

If you really would like to use the API, use ContextReplacementPlugin plugin according to [How to prevent moment.js from loading locales with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384360/how-to-prevent-moment-js-from-loading-locales-with-webpack). Although, the benefits of the API (e.g., `.entireMainFor("en")`) are lost, because you would have to duplicate effort changing the plugin to reflect what you need. For example:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = 
...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/cldr-data$/, /supplemental/)
  ]
};
```

Thanks for all the help @bebraw and @sokra.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go through `require.context`, it would look like this on consumer side:

```
var req = require.context('cldr-data/supplemental');
var likelySubtags = req('./likelySubtags.json');
```

That doesn't look very nice to me. I tried against `require.context('cldr-data')` but then we're again in the world of slow builds. I think in that case it will have to traverse whole package so it can build the lookup.

`var likelySubtags = require('cldr-data/supplemental/likelySubtags');` seems like the sanest option to me at the moment.

Perhaps there could be a Webpack adapter in between that would hide that `require.context` thing as above? You could easily end up with an API like `require('cldr-data').supplemental('likelySubtags'). That`req`part can be dynamic so this should work. You would just write the missing`./`and`.json` there. Of course you are free to change the API to your liking. This was just the first idea that I came up with.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Using the plugin according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384360/how-to-prevent-moment-js-from-loading-locales-with-webpack was the best solution for me.