# React/Redux bundle.js is too big

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a small React project. The bundle.js generated by Webpack is 6.3Mb. How can I decrease the size to be <2.0Mb? (2Mb is still big but acceptable). Complete source code is at [github](https://github.com/dsun29/fullstackcms/)

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: [
        './app/components/app.jsx'
    ],
    output: {
        path: './public',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'app'],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ['happypack/loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: [
                    'style',
                    'css',
                    'autoprefixer?browsers=last 3 versions',
                    'sass?outputStyle=expanded'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                loaders: [
                    'url?limit=8192',
                    'img'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Fullstack Rebel',
            template: './app/templates/index_template.ejs'
        }),
        new HappyPack({
            loaders: ['babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015']
        })
    ]
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "fullstackcms",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A Content Management System Made of NodeJS, MongoDB, React, Redux and Bootstrap",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --colors"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/dsun29/fullstackcms"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.14.2",
    "connect-mongo": "^1.3.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.24.0",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "express-session": "^1.14.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "history": "^1.17.0",
    "img-loader": "^1.2.2",
    "immutable": "^3.7.6",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.10",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "node-twitter-api": "^1.8.0",
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.3",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1",
    "react-google-login": "^2.5.1",
    "react-modal-dialog": "^3.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-router": "^2.7.0",
    "react-tinymce": "^0.5.1",
    "react-twitter-widgets": "^0.2.4",
    "redux": "^3.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "reqwest": "^2.0.5",
    "routes": "^2.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.11.0",
    "babel-regenerator-runtime": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.16.3",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.11.6",
    "chai": "^3.4.1",
    "chai-immutable": "^1.5.3",
    "eslint": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.2.0",
    "happypack": "^2.2.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
    "mocha": "^3.0.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.3",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  }
}
```

**Some results from webpack-bundle-size-analyzer**

```
active-event-stack: 402.98 KB (17.3%)
  lodash: 401.81 KB (99.7%)
  <self>: 1.17 KB (0.292%)
react-bootstrap: 382.86 KB (16.4%)
  warning: 1.76 KB (0.461%)
  <self>: 381.1 KB (99.5%)
react-router: 156.83 KB (6.73%)
  history: 49.02 KB (31.3%)
    warning: 1.76 KB (3.60%)
    <self>: 47.26 KB (96.4%)
  warning: 1.76 KB (1.13%)
  query-string: 1.45 KB (0.922%)
  hoist-non-react-statics: 1.35 KB (0.864%)
  <self>: 103.24 KB (65.8%)
immutable: 139.14 KB (5.98%)
react-overlays: 69.06 KB (2.97%)
  warning: 1.76 KB (2.56%)
  <self>: 67.29 KB (97.4%)
dynamics.js: 60.12 KB (2.58%)
react-tinymce: 49.09 KB (2.11%)
  lodash: 43.66 KB (88.9%)
  <self>: 5.43 KB (11.1%)
babel-runtime: 45.11 KB (1.94%)
  core-js: 40.78 KB (90.4%)
  <self>: 4.33 KB (9.59%)
jss: 42.23 KB (1.81%)
fbjs: 32.61 KB (1.40%)
react-modal-dialog: 26.36 KB (1.13%)
redux: 22.36 KB (0.960%)
react-redux: 19.37 KB (0.832%)
reqwest: 18.76 KB (0.806%)
dom-helpers: 15.56 KB (0.668%)
lodash: 12.9 KB (0.554%)
uncontrollable: 9.57 KB (0.411%)
style-loader: 6.99 KB (0.300%)
css-vendor: 6.11 KB (0.263%)
react-prop-types: 6.04 KB (0.260%)
react-center-component: 5.87 KB (0.252%)
react-jss: 5.34 KB (0.229%)
node-libs-browser: 5.17 KB (0.222%)
  process: 5.17 KB (100%)
  <self>: 0 B (0.00%)
react-google-login: 3.99 KB (0.171%)
deep-equal: 3.8 KB (0.163%)
keycode: 2.7 KB (0.116%)
object-assign: 1.95 KB (0.0836%)
invariant: 1.48 KB (0.0636%)
css-loader: 1.47 KB (0.0632%)
jss-vendor-prefixer: 1.39 KB (0.0596%)
jss-nested: 1.18 KB (0.0506%)
jss-camel-case: 1.13 KB (0.0484%)
hoist-non-react-statics: 1.09 KB (0.0470%)
classnames: 1.08 KB (0.0462%)
symbol-observable: 1.07 KB (0.0461%)
jss-px: 936 B (0.0393%)
redux-thunk: 529 B (0.0222%)
webpack: 251 B (0.0105%)
strict-uri-encode: 182 B (0.00763%)
react-dom: 63 B (0.00264%)
is-browser: 22 B (0.000923%)
reqwest xhr2: 15 B (0.000629%)
<self>: 119.37 KB (5.13%)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you can do. I suggest to create two configurations of webpack. First for development where we don't care about bundle size and second for production where bundle will be optimized.

1. Remove completely source-map (delete devtool line). You don't need it in production mode.
2. Use production mode. Add this entry to plugins

   ```
   plugins: [
       new webpack.DefinePlugin({
           'process.env': {
               'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
           }
       })
   ],
   ```
3. Use `webpack -p` for building
4. To minimize size of libraries you should only import functions that
   you use. For example if you need a few functions from lodash like
   `forEach, orderBy, map`.

   ```
   import forEach from 'lodash/forEach'
   import orderBy from 'lodash/orderBy'
   import map from 'lodash/map'
   ```

Answer (score 7):

Your bundle is huge because of the source map. When creating the bundle, remove this line:

```
devtool: 'inline-source-map'
```

This will also remove the source map during development however, so can do something like this in package.json:

"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --colors",
    "build": "webpack -p"
  },

Webpack -p will start the build mode for webpack, and will also minify your code, making it smaller.

And in your webpack.config.js:

```
const args = require('yargs').argv;
const build = args.p;


devtool: build ? undefined : 'inline-source-map',
```

This will remove the source map when building.

There are better methods to identify build, such as NODE_ENV, and you should look at the [devtool options](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool), if you need a source map in production.

Answer (score 1):

You are using 'inline-source-map' as devtool option. This adds sourcemaps inside your bundle, which are actually bigger than code itself. Try another option from webpack documentation.

Comment: changed from inline-source-map to source-map. Size is 2.53Mb now from 6.5Mb. Many thanks!! Any more suggestion to make it even smaller?

Answer (score 1):

This may still be of interest to some people so I'll throw in an additional answer...

React functional components, aka React hooks, introduced in V16 use less code than class-based components so that's another option

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but would question the need for [active-event-stack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/active-event-stack) which seems pretty huge for what it is.  If it's a child dependency then consider something else.  Also, the bootstrap library you're using is huge, you may be able to just use the specific components you want and reduce the output.

---

Comment, came into this answer as I have an application using material-ui with a few components and some router interactions, and my uncompressed bundle size is 873k including styles and a couple images.  You should also gzip it, and serve it gzipped by the webserver.  Mine gzipped is (180KB)... YMMV.