# Creating a standalone build using webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, web-deployment

[Webpack how to build production code and how to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35054082/webpack-how-to-build-production-code-and-how-to-use-it)

- Above question came very near to answering this. But I am stressing on the second part.
- I am new to Nodejs let alone Webpack. I tried this tutorial
  https://blog.risingstack.com/using-react-with-webpack-tutorial/
  Which really threw light into many aspects of Webpack.
- But, what I want is a build which can run "on its own", that is, without node modules and other unnecessary files.
- I tried Webpack -p  with production configuration and that runs fine and creates a dist directory. And I thought that directory  was what I was looking for. But I can't find a way to run it.
- What am I missing ?

EDIT:

- I tried to run means i tried to open the index.html
- I looked at the browser console now and its showing file not found for both my JS file and CSS file.
- I will provide a screenshot of the console output. My dist directory contains four files index.html, main-d9103c44e6f452183f46.min.css, main-d9103c44e6f452183f46.min.js, webpack.stats.json.
- As I mentioned above, pretty much a noob. If you tell me what information I should provide, I'll be happy to provide that. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to run this on the server with node? or on a client's browser? Webpack is usually used to generate files that are served to browsers.

Comment: I ran the app in a virtualbox successfully using npm start.
Then I made a production build and tried to run the files in dist folder separately using a browser in my local. And it didn't work.

Comment: Gonna need a lot more info. What error messages are you getting? What _exactly_ did you do when you say you "tried to run" it? More detail is always helpful.

Comment: `dist` should contain everything you need run the application, including an `index.html` file that contains a relative path to your bundle.js that was generated. Now that we have index.html and bundle.js, that's all we need. Take a peek here: https://github.com/mikechabot/react-boilerplate

Comment: The react boilerplate is working as expected