# MSBuild and Webpack

Tags: msbuild, webpack, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, msbuild-task

I am developing an Angular2 application in VS2015 and have a webpack bundling and minification environment set up for the same.

This is my webpack.conf.js

```js
switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
    case 'prod':
    case 'production':
        module.exports = require('./config/webpack.prod');
        break;
    case 'test':
    case 'testing':
        //module.exports = require('./config/webpack.test');
        break;
    case 'dev':
    case 'development':
    default:
        module.exports = require('./config/webpack.dev');
}
```

I have also installed a webpack task runner which invokes this with the following commands

```
cmd /c SET NODE_ENV=development&& webpack -d --color
```

and

```
cmd /c SET NODE_ENV=production&& webpack -p --color
```

The setup seems to work fine. However, I want to integrate this with my TFS builds CI. The webpack command should fire after the project is built and report a build failure incase the webpack build fails. I have tried to incorporate the following code in my .csproj file

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
<Exec Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Debug'" Command="cmd /c SET NODE_ENV=production&& webpack -p --color">
</Exec>
</Target>
```

It failed with an error 9009

After that I tried, starting the command up from the node_modules folder where webpack was installed

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
<Exec Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Debug'" Command="./node_modules/.bin cmd /c SET NODE_ENV=production&& webpack -p --color">
</Exec>
</Target>
```

still in vain. Even if I get this to work, I am not sure if it would cause the VS build to fail if it encounters an error in webpack.

How do I go ahead with this?

Comment: Maybe you just need a white-space? In the second-last snippet, replace this `SET NODE_ENV=production&&` with this - `SET NODE_ENV=production &&`. I know it's silly. But it's what I could offer! :D

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Put different scripts in package.json for development and production mode. Then on 'AfterBuild' event of visual studio, call those scripts on different configurations.

Add following two scripts, **'buildDev'** and **'buildProd'** in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "buildDev": "SET NODE_ENV=development && webpack -d --color",
    "buildProd": "SET NODE_ENV=production && webpack -p --color",
  }
```

In AfterBuild events of visual studio add these two conditional commands:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Debug'" Command="npm run buildDev" />
    <Exec Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Release'" Command="npm run buildProd" />
  </Target>
```

And finally webpack.conf.js like this:

```
switch (process.env.NODE_ENV.trim()) {
    case 'prod':
    case 'production':
        module.exports = require('./config/webpack.prod');
        break;
    case 'dev':
    case 'development':
    default:
        module.exports = require('./config/webpack.dev');
        break;
}
```

> **Important Note:** Make sure to **use trim() function with process.env.NODE_ENV** as cmd will treat the blank space in the command **"SET NODE_ENV=development && webpack -d --color** as character and append it in NODE_ENV variable. So when we are setting it as 'development', it actually gets set as **(development + whitespace)**.

Comment: Isn't this going to be really slow?  This implies you're running wepack on every C# build, and that might easily add 20s to your otherwise 1s build times.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne I agree, this will increase build time. Depending upon the situation one can have different combination of running webpack commands. For e.g. I make use of webpack --watch command while in debug mode and make use of above mentioned solution only in release mode i.e. Nightly builds.
If you can think of any better solution please suggest :)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply - I'll give it a shot, but I guess my chances aren't great...

Comment: Fyi:
If anyone is getting 3x size of their bundle  .js file then know it's the -d parameter causing this with Webpack 2 (it's causing source map files to be baked into it). https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2445

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019 the following may work ```<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Debug'" Command="npm run buildDev" />
    <Exec Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Release'" Command="npm run buildProd" />
  </Target>```

Answer (score 3):

For TFS CI build, you can refer to these steps to achieve your requirement.

1. Add npm step 
   [image]
2. Add Command Line step
   [image]

Note: There is –bail argument, which is required otherwise the step/task will be succeed even though webpack command throws exception.

Also, you can add variable in build definition (variable tab)