# Visual studio not updating to code changes being made

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build

Had a roam around Stack Overflow to try and find ways of solving this and am yet to come across a method that works. Have a project built in C# with an Angular front end. Recently published to a server, which works fine. However now when I try to make changes to the code locally and run in debug, the build does not pick up on any of the changes being made, I've tried restarting VS, updating VS, restarting my PC, cleaning the solution, having Configurations Manager ensure that the project is not run on old builds. Anyone know why this kind of thing is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sometimes cleaning the solution doesn't remove everything - try deleting all the `bin` and `obj` folders and rebuilding.

Comment: Does the angular project use webpack at all to build it?  Put some information about your solution structure perhaps?  Is it a browser caching issue (Ctrl+F5)?

Comment: @stuartd I have tried this solution before and it doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: @Andez It was an issue with my webpack - I cut out the middleware when pushing out to live and just completely forgot about it when running again in debug - Thanks for the help !

Comment: Yeah it has caught me out a few times.  You can look at incorporating a webpack build into a visual studio/tfx build - check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40993795/msbuild-and-webpack