# How to remove unnecessary modules from bundles

Tags: webpack

I'm using `webpack` to create output bundles for an `angular2` project. I'm creating two bundles containing project codes and vendors:

```
entry: {
    main: './src/main',
    vendors: ['./node_modules/@angular/core', './node_modules/moment']
},
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: [nodeModulesDir],
        loader: 'babel'
    }]
},
```

With a brief book into vendors bundle, I see all the locale files of `moment` are included in vendor bundle, but I need just `de_DE`. how can I exclude unnecessary locales?

Comment: @FarzadYZ I've just defined the `vendors` entry point and `webpack` is importing them, since they're required somewhere in moment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent moment.js from loading locales with webpack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384360/how-to-prevent-moment-js-from-loading-locales-with-webpack)

Comment: @FarzadYZ Great! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this could help

[GitHub - jmblog / **how-to-optimize-momentjs-with-webpack**](https://github.com/jmblog/how-to-optimize-momentjs-with-webpack)

Create react app configs contain this too

```
new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
```