# How to exclude dependencies from webpack in a angular-cli project (like locales in momentjs)

Tags: angular, webpack, momentjs, angular-cli

When I import libraries like momentjs in a webpack project webpack automatically includes all their optional dependencies in the bundle too. In the case of momentjs when I do this:

```
import * as moment from 'momentjs'
```

I add 200kb into my bundle because this automatically includes ALL possible locales. Locales are 150kb where the library itself is only 50kb. [In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384360/how-to-prevent-moment-js-from-loading-locales-with-webpack) its described how to exclude those dependencies in the webpack configuration with the help of the ContextReplacementPlugin.

How can I do that in an angular-cli project where I don't have direct access to the webpack configuration (unless I eject the config, which has other side effects).

Comment: you can consider use https://date-fns.org/ as it allows you to bring only the code you need.

Comment: thanks for the link. I will use this in my own code for sure! Problem is, in this case, charts.js is importing momentjs. Its normally an optional dependency when you load it with a script tag, but its always auto-included with webpack.

Comment: FYI: when I came across this question I already was hopeless and started to write feature request on `ng-cli` GitHub [#5166](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5166) as i don't like the idea of ejecting myself to achieve this

Comment: yes, the situation seems to be not so good, even the proposed solution via ContextReplacementPlugin is not a solution but only a workaround. I don't understand why momentjs doesn't change its behaviour. But thanks for your angular-cli issue, I just upvoted it.

Comment: @MarcoRinck Filipe Silva pointed to yet another workaround which does not require altering webpack config [moment/moment#1435 (comment)](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1435#issuecomment-240983788). I have not tried it yet, but hopefully will find a bit of time this week

Comment: I just tried that and after deleting node_modules/moment/src and importing moment like described in the comment my bundle still contains 212kb of momentjs. So, it changes nothing. But even if it did, it would still be a hack since you need to ensure to delete this folder before doing any build.

Comment: @MarcoRinck Did you solve this issue? Same problem with me.

Comment: @AmitChigadani unfortunately not