# Laravel mix webpack - Ignore locales when importing Moment.js

Tags: laravel, webpack, momentjs, laravel-mix

I would like to load 2 locales `en-gb` and `fr-ch` only from **Moment.js** , then assign the `moment` class to the scope`window` to use the library everywhere in my Vuejs components.

Currently, my `app.js` has this require line:

```
window.moment = require('moment')
```

I am suspecting it can be accomplished thanks to the [solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384360/how-to-prevent-moment-js-from-loading-locales-with-webpack/25426019#25426019) (adding **IgnorePlugin** and **ContextReplacementPlugin** to `webpack.config.js`):

```
plugins.push(new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en-gb|fr-ch/))
module.exports.plugins = plugins;
```

OR

```
plugins.push(new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/))
module.exports.plugins = plugins;
```

Where should you add these pieces of code (`webpack.config.js` and/or `app.js` and/or `webpack.mix.js`) to ignore all other locales when importing `momentjs`?

Answer (score 2):

```
  mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)
    ]
  })
```

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/laravel-mix-prevent-momentjs-locales

Answer (score 0):

```
mix.webpackConfig( webpack => {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)
  ]
});
```

this way you dont have to import webpack on the top of your file, which sometimes can cause errors.

and you also can put other necessary options like this

```
mix.webpackConfig( webpack => {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
    alias: {
      '@': __dirname + '/resources',
      '@root': __dirname,
      '@pages': __dirname + '/resources/js/pages'
    },
    fallback: { "path": false },
  },
});
```