# How to specify filename pattern in dynamic import with Webpack?

Tags: webpack, dynamic-import

If we do

```
import(`intl/locale-data/jsonp/${language}.js`);
```

Then all files in `intl/locale-data/jsonp/*.js` are compiled to output.

Is there a way to only compile specific locale files if we know that `language` can only be `en` or `de`?

Comment: maybe the only way is just specify all the variants through `if...else...` or `switch`. or maybe remove extra files from that directory manually.

Comment: @skyboyer I was afraid of that but thanks.

Comment: Use `ContextReplacementPlugin`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25426019/145899