# How to use CodeMirror runmode standalone version in a webpack setup

Tags: javascript, webpack, codemirror

I'm using CodeMirror as a simple syntax highlighter (≠ code editor) with the [`runmode` **addon**](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_runmode). In order to save some bandwidth to users, i want to switch to `runmode-standlone.js` version, which is also included in the package but doesn't bring the whole `CodeMirror` power and weight attached.

The problem, as [referenced by the library author](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/5175#issuecomment-356537759) is that `CodeMirror` library is listed as dependency of each `mode` (the lang packages):

> you have to somehow convince your bundler to load the runmode-standalone shim instead of the regular core library for that dependency. — Author

**Anyone managed to do this?**

#### What i've already tried

Note, i've setup an alias so when i reference `codemirror`, it imports the standalone version (just FYI, because i've also tried without it)

```
// webpack.config.js
resolve: {
  alias: {
   codemirror$: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/codemirror/addon/runmode/runmode-standalone.js")
  }
}
```

1. All combinations of `script-loader`, `imports-loader` to try to execute mode modules as normal scripts

```
import "codemirror";
// same as import "codemirror/addon/runmode/runmode-standalone.js";

// nope
import "script-loader!codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript";

// nope
import "imports-loader?define=>false!codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript";

// nope
import "imports-loader?define=>false,module=>false,require=>false!codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript";
```

2. A similar strategy to what's suggested for ignoring `moment.js` locales ([repo](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2416), [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384360/how-to-prevent-moment-js-from-loading-locales-with-webpack/25426019#25426019), using `webpackIgnorePlugin`

```
// codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js import looks like

(function(mod) {
  if (typeof exports == "object" && typeof module == "object") // CommonJS
    mod(require("../../lib/codemirror"));
  else if (typeof define == "function" && define.amd) // AMD
    define(["../../lib/codemirror"], mod);
  else // Plain browser env
    mod(CodeMirror);
})(function(CodeMirror) {
...
```

So i've tried to make it ignore

```
new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
  resourceRegExp: /^\.\.\/lib\/codemirror$/,
  contextRegExp: /^codemirror\/mode\/(.*)/
});
```

#### Setup details

Using `codemirror@5.47.0` and `webpack@4.29.6`

Answer (score 0):

Configure webpack to use [externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/).

> The externals configuration option provides a way of excluding dependencies from the output bundles. Instead, the created bundle relies on that dependency to be present in the consumer's (any end-user application) environment.

```
externals: {
  '../lib/codemirror': 'CodeMirror', // for mode/meta.js
  '../../lib/codemirror': 'CodeMirror' // for mode/[mode]/[mode].js
}
```