# ReactJS TypeScript: Attempted import error: 'ActionButtonProps' is not exported from './ActionButton'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, antd

I have a TypeScript ReactJS project created using `create-react-app` and I'm trying to include code from the `antd` npm package into the project so that I can test code changes in an effort to contribute to the `antd` open-source project.

I've taken the repo's code and placed it in `/src/antd` directory.

I've also copied its `./tsconfig.json` and `./webpack.config.js` files over to the root directory of my created `create-react-app` project.

When I attempt to run the project, I receive the following "Failed to compile" error:

```
./src/antd/components/modal/index.tsx
Attempted import error: 'ActionButtonProps' is not exported from './ActionButton'.
```

In the `./src/antd/components/modal/index.tsx` file there is the following line:

```
export { ActionButtonProps } from './ActionButton';
```

And in `./src/antd/components/modal/ActionButton.tsx` it exports the following interface:

```
export interface ActionButtonProps {
  type?: LegacyButtonType;
  actionFn?: (...args: any[]) => any | PromiseLike<any>;
  closeModal: Function;
  autoFocus?: boolean;
  prefixCls: string;
  buttonProps?: ButtonProps;
}
```

The following is the copied `webpack.config.js` file from the `antd` repo:

```
/* eslint no-param-reassign: 0 */
// This config is for building dist files
const getWebpackConfig = require('@ant-design/tools/lib/getWebpackConfig');
const IgnoreEmitPlugin = require('ignore-emit-webpack-plugin');
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');
const EsbuildPlugin = require('esbuild-webpack-plugin').default;
const darkVars = require('./scripts/dark-vars');
const compactVars = require('./scripts/compact-vars');

const { webpack } = getWebpackConfig;

// noParse still leave `require('./locale' + name)` in dist files
// ignore is better: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25384360
function ignoreMomentLocale(webpackConfig) {
  delete webpackConfig.module.noParse;
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/));
}

function addLocales(webpackConfig) {
  let packageName = 'antd-with-locales';
  if (webpackConfig.entry['antd.min']) {
    packageName += '.min';
  }
  webpackConfig.entry[packageName] = './index-with-locales.js';
  webpackConfig.output.filename = '[name].js';
}

function externalMoment(config) {
  config.externals.moment = {
    root: 'moment',
    commonjs2: 'moment',
    commonjs: 'moment',
    amd: 'moment',
  };
}

function injectWarningCondition(config) {
  config.module.rules.forEach(rule => {
    // Remove devWarning if needed
    if (rule.test.test('test.tsx')) {
      rule.use = [
        ...rule.use,
        {
          loader: 'string-replace-loader',
          options: {
            search: 'devWarning(',
            replace: "if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') devWarning(",
          },
        },
      ];
    }
  });
}

function processWebpackThemeConfig(themeConfig, theme, vars) {
  themeConfig.forEach(config => {
    ignoreMomentLocale(config);
    externalMoment(config);

    // rename default entry to ${theme} entry
    Object.keys(config.entry).forEach(entryName => {
      config.entry[entryName.replace('antd', `antd.${theme}`)] = config.entry[entryName];
      delete config.entry[entryName];
    });

    // apply ${theme} less variables
    config.module.rules.forEach(rule => {
      // filter less rule
      if (rule.test instanceof RegExp && rule.test.test('.less')) {
        const lessRule = rule.use[rule.use.length - 1];
        if (lessRule.options.lessOptions) {
          lessRule.options.lessOptions.modifyVars = vars;
        } else {
          lessRule.options.modifyVars = vars;
        }
      }
    });

    const themeReg = new RegExp(`${theme}(.min)?\\.js(\\.map)?$`);
    // ignore emit ${theme} entry js & js.map file
    config.plugins.push(new IgnoreEmitPlugin(themeReg));
  });
}

const webpackConfig = getWebpackConfig(false);
const webpackDarkConfig = getWebpackConfig(false);
const webpackCompactConfig = getWebpackConfig(false);

webpackConfig.forEach(config => {
  injectWarningCondition(config);
});

if (process.env.RUN_ENV === 'PRODUCTION') {
  webpackConfig.forEach(config => {
    ignoreMomentLocale(config);
    externalMoment(config);
    addLocales(config);
    // Reduce non-minified dist files size
    config.optimization.usedExports = true;
    // use esbuild
    if (process.env.ESBUILD || process.env.CSB_REPO) {
      config.optimization.minimizer[0] = new EsbuildPlugin({
        target: 'chrome49',
      });
    }

    config.plugins.push(
      new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
        analyzerMode: 'static',
        openAnalyzer: false,
        reportFilename: '../report.html',
      }),
    );
  });

  processWebpackThemeConfig(webpackDarkConfig, 'dark', darkVars);
  processWebpackThemeConfig(webpackCompactConfig, 'compact', compactVars);
}

module.exports = [...webpackConfig, ...webpackDarkConfig, ...webpackCompactConfig];
```

The following is the copied `tsconfig.json` file from the `antd` repo:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "lib",
    "es"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

The following is `src/antd/index.js`:

```
/* eslint no-console:0 */
function pascalCase(name) {
  return name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1).replace(/-(\w)/g, (m, n) => n.toUpperCase());
}

// Just import style for https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/3745
const req = require.context('./components', true, /^\.\/[^_][\w-]+\/style\/index\.tsx?$/);

req.keys().forEach(mod => {
  let v = req(mod);
  if (v && v.default) {
    v = v.default;
  }
  const match = mod.match(/^\.\/([^_][\w-]+)\/index\.tsx?$/);
  if (match && match[1]) {
    if (match[1] === 'message' || match[1] === 'notification') {
      // message & notification should not be capitalized
      exports[match[1]] = v;
    } else {
      exports[pascalCase(match[1])] = v;
    }
  }
});

module.exports = require('./components');
```

What am I doing wrong that the compiler is failing at build time to not see the interface being exported by `ActionButton.tsx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this was a limitation with `create-react-app` ReactJS projects and how they use webpack or babel to hotload file changes.

The problems don't appear in distributed packages of `antd` when adding them to your project because the need to hotload its contents is removed when it has been compiled.

The workaround for me was to use [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/porting-from-create-react-app-to-gatsby/) to run my ReactJS project instead of a `create-react-app` one.